# google recaptcha error message

Tags: recaptcha, gxt

I am working on  recaptcha code in my application. I would like to know if there is a default (inbuilt) method to display error message(on validation fail)? I couldn't find one, currently I am manually adding an error label on validation fail.Now the problem is I would like to remove the label once the user refresh the captcha to do another submit. Since the response textbox is provided by recaptcha , how do I attach a listener to it through java, so I can hide the error label on select event or something. Or is there a better way to handle this scenario?Its a gwt project and I am not familiar with javascript. I tried assigning a variable named  `incorrect_try_again`(which is already available in the captcha object )with error message, but that didn't work. Could anyone tell me what's the purpose of that variable and how address the problem?

```
    public static native void create(String key, String div, String theme, String lang, int tabIndex,
            String instructionVisual, String instructionAudio, String playAgain, String cantHereThis,
            String visualChalange, String audioChalange, String refreshButton, String helpButton,
            String incorrectTryAgain)
    /*-{
        $wnd.Recaptcha.create(key, "recaptcha_div", {
        theme:theme,
        lang:lang,
        tabindex:tabIndex,
        custom_translations:{
        instructions_visual : instructionVisual,
        instructions_audio : instructionAudio,
        play_again : playAgain,
        cant_hear_this : cantHereThis,
        visual_challenge : visualChalange,
        audio_challenge : audioChalange,
        refresh_btn : refreshButton,
        help_btn : helpButton,
        incorrect_try_again : incorrectTryAgain
        }
        });
    }-*/;
```

Thanks in advance.

Ok. I found this article which states `you can add '&error=incorrect-captcha-sol' to the challenge request URL, and the user will get an error code.`
Not sure how to do this since I am not a js guy. :(

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: ok, figured how to fix the issue.

Comment: created a new captcha on validation fail and appended the &error= parameter as mentioned above to the public key.